# Github pull request get commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a question regarding open pull requests. I made a pull request to merge my branch, 'featureA' to the branch 'develop'.

If someone else makes commits in the same pull request(not closed) which updates some of my code, how can I update my branch 'featureA' with the most recent commits?

Do I need to copy and paste it over to my branch or is there a specific way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried just pull your branch locally? Someone else making commits in the same PR means they've updated your remote branch, so I'd expect you to just be able to pull to get those changes locally.

Comment: The pull request follows the branch, not the other way around.